# Is there a way to send new data from nodejs to jade after a page has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, pug

For example I can send a data when a page is about to be rendered:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
 res.render('filename', {title: 'File Name', FIles: JSON.stringify(doc)});
}
```

Lets say filename.jade there is a button that sends data back to node js, to '/getdoc' route. and '/getdoc' doesn't render any new page but rather saves the data on a database. and sends back a data. The data that is send back `doc` is a dictionary of all the documents saved on the database:

```
router.post('/getcode', function(req, res){
 res.header('text/html').send(doc);
}
```

I have tried res.send and res.json. If I use res.json or res.send then on client side I retrieved it like this: `!{JSON.stringify(doc)}`

Comment: You can use `res.json` to send a json document back to client.

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't work. I have tried res.send and res.json. If I use res.json or res.send then on client side I retrieved it like this: `!{JSON.stringify(doc)}`

Comment: Could you explain more on how you plan to use the data on the client and why you can not use the above methods?

Comment: After I use res.send or res.json, on the server side I print console.log(doc), I get the correct items, but on the client side When I print console.log(doc), I don't get the correct items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: **Yes**

But first things first, JADE is a rendering engine, that takes jade file & data(optional) and renders an HTML page **on the server side**. The app pipeline then sends this page to the client, which displays it. There is **NO** jade on the client.

Now, Solution for your problem:

- Your route looks fine, use `res.json` to send back data as JSON.
- Use client side scripting (vanilla JS, or any other library like jQuery) for calling that route through AJAX (when button is clicked), and update the DOM from the data received.

I hope this helps. Comment/Reply for further clarification.